# rails 3 mod rewrite with refraction gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mod-rewrite, redirect, heroku

I'm trying to use a subdomain beta.somedomain.com and I would like it to redirect to somedomain.heroku.com/beta

I'm using the refraction gem here:

https://github.com/pivotal/refraction

but I can't seem to get it to work.

Tried:

## refraction_rules.rb    in intializers

```
Refraction.configure do |req|
   if req.host == 'beta.somedomain.com'
     req.rewrite! "http://beta.somedomain.com/beta/#{req.path}"
   end
end
```

and

```
Refraction.configure do |req|
  if req.host == 'beta.somedomain.com'
    req.rewrite! "http://somedomain.heroku.com/beta/#{req.path}"
  end
end
```

Also tried

```
req.permanent! :host => "beta.somedomain.com"
```

Instead of rewrite

## production.rb

```
config.middleware.insert_before(::Rack::Lock, ::Refraction)
```

But neither works, both just direct me to root '/'

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the built-in routing functionality of Rails 3:

```
constraints :subdomain => "beta" do
  match "/(:page)" => redirect { |params| "http://somedomain.heroku.com/beta/#{params[:page]}" }
end
```

Check the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) or this [Rails Dispatch article](http://www.railsdispatch.com/posts/rails-routing) for more information.